# How to solve the problem with duplication when reading firestore data?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a customized screen .dart, in which I need to display a list of the firestore variable "testfield".
The problem is that each document duplicates the configured screen with itself.dart, and is not displayed in it as a list, as in other applications.
For example, the screen contains a name, a description that cannot be read from the firestore, but also contains a column, which should already contain a list obtained from the firestore (code example below), but everything does not work as it should and the list leaves huge gaps, and inserts (duplicates) between them my customized screen.
How is it possible to fix this?

My screen code (test stand):

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:operbooktest/TestMain.dart';
import 'package:operbooktest/settings_pages.dart';
import 'package:operbooktest/test3.dart';

class Checking extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "Checking";

  @override
  State<Checking> createState() => _CheckingState();
}

class _CheckingState extends State<Checking> {
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getthosedocuments() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('testfz')
        //.limit(1)
        .get();
    return snapshot;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: getthosedocuments(),
          builder: (context, snapshotsub) {
            if (snapshotsub.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            final docs = snapshotsub.data!.docs;
            return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: snapshotsub.data?.size,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final doc = docs.elementAt(index);
                return Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          NewWidget(),
                          Button_Chapter_the_Articles(
                              ButtonChapterTheArticles: ((doc.data()
                              as Map<String, dynamic>)['testfield']
                              as String? ?? ""),
                              NavigatorTheChapterPageButton: const TestMain()),
                          //NewWidget()
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewWidget({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                'Title',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontFamily: 'TimesNewRoman',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  letterSpacing: 1,
                  height: 1.5,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                'Text',
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontFamily: 'TimesNewRoman',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  letterSpacing: 1,
                  height: 1.5,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 50,
        ),
        Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                '\t\t\t\tText',
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontFamily: 'TimesNewRoman',
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  letterSpacing: 1,
                  height: 1.3,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        // Text((doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['article2'] as String? ??""),
        // Text((doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['article1'] as String? ??""),
        //Text('$doc['title1']'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshots:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwdMO.png)

An example of how it should be (a screenshot drawn):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsbTd.png)

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to remove the 'Title' and 'Text' widgets from NewWidget() as you are replicating the number of 'Title' and 'Text' widgets to the number of items in the list.

Then you can use a column to wrap the 'Title', 'Text', and the Futurebuilder widget. This way, the 'Title' and 'Text' widgets are created once at the top of the page, and below it will be a dynamic list of items

Quick example:

```
Scaffold(
 child: SafeArea(
  child: Column(
     children: [
        'Title' widget,
        'Text' widget,
        'FutureBuilder' widget
      ]
    )
  )
)
```